# Authorization Attribute call on Index method is causing infinity loop

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionfilterattribute

I am trying to use authorization attribute on index method as shown below but it causes an infinity loop of index method call.

```
[Authorization]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //here is controller code..
}
```

Code for Authorization Attribute is as follow.

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //try
        //{
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["password"] != null)
            {
                string username = HttpContext.Current.Session["username"].ToString();
                string password = HttpContext.Current.Session["password"].ToString();
                string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;  
                string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
                if (username == null || username == "" || password == null || password == "")
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "User",
                        action = "LogOut",
                    }));
                    //base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                }
                else
                {

                    //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/"+controllerName+"/"+actionName);
                    //return;
                    //filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    //{
                       // controller = controllerName,
                       // action = actionName,
                   // })); ...Removed this redirection and it worked for me.
                    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                }
            }
            else
            {

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                {
                    controller = "User",
                    action = "LogOut",
                }));
                //base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        //}
        //catch(Exception ex)
        //{
        //    throw ex;
        //}
       
    }
}
```

I am trying to use it with session created with user login and without login it redirects to login page but after successfull login when I try to redirect to Index methhod of another controller it causes infinite loop of redirect, giving error in browser "redirected too many times."

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen when you redirect to the action that is decorated with `[Authorization]`? Browser calls action -> attribute redirects to same action -> browser calls action again -> attribute redirects to same action -> attribute redirects to same action -> browser calls action again -> attribute redirects to same action -> attribute redirects to same action -> browser calls action again -> attribute redirects to same action.

Comment: It's not really clear what your actual goal here is. What should this filter actually be doing?

Comment: after login success the application will redirect to start page in which I have given link to a page which shows list of employees. The controller for that page is  EmployeeController and the default method is index method which shows list of employees. Now when i click on the link to this index method it first goes to Employee controller then check for Authorization Attribute which redirects to index method of Employee controller but after one redirect it does not stop and again go for check for authorization attribute and again redirect to index method and this goes on continuously.

Comment: OK, but I don't understand: why is a filter on a specific controller action, redirecting to that same controller action? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I want to make a filter which does not allow user to direct open a link without login. So before returning the view i want to check that user is logged in or not. If logged in than user can access pages else user gets redirected to log in page.

Comment: How do you plan to differentiate between "open direct link without login" and "been to login page, was already logged in"? Because at the moment your code basically says "if there isn't a username or password, redirect to the login page. Otherwise, if the username is empty, or the password is empty, redirect to the login page. In all other scenarios, redirect to the same page the user is trying to access." - That doesn't consider how the user came to the page.

Comment: I am using visual studio and when i run application from any other file it will start with login page but when i try to run application from a view page it directly opens that page and what i want is even if i try to run application from another view page it opens login page first not the selected view page.

Comment: OK, you'll need to work out a way of determining how the user got to the page. At the moment all you're determining is if the session contains a username and password, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help I will work on that.

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I removed the code of else section in which i was redirecting to the controller name and action name, it worked for me.

Comment: That is what I was telling you from the beginning. Your code still doesn't distinguish between "user loaded the page directly [but was already logged in]" and "user came from the login page", which is what you stated your goal to be.